# Java Servlet textarea

Tags: java, servlet

я только начал изучать servlet'ы, и в интернете куча примеров с созданием Hello servlet. Но как создать более сложные не обьясняется. К примеру мне нужен servlet с  использованием textarea для ввода   математической формулы с клавиатуры. Может ктото показать пример? Ну или может есть ссылка на толковый ресурс?

Comment: Вы не примеры ищите, а учебники читайте. Когда понимаешь принципы, можешь реализовать всё, даже если ни разу не видел примера.

Comment: У меня сжатые сроки в этом вопросе, я должен разобраться хотябы поверхностно, а потом уже и учебник почитаю, это полезное дело.